# I am doing an assignment based on java and mysql.Any suggestions to improve my code

Tags: java, mysql

My question:
The goal is to write a parser in Java that parses web server access log file, loads the log to MySQL and checks if a given IP makes more than a certain number of requests for the given duration.

The tool takes `startDate`, `duration` and `threshold` as command line arguments. `startDate` is of `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss` format, `duration` can take only `hourly`, `daily` as inputs and `threshold` can be an integer.

I tired to execute to it, but is there any suggestions to optimize my code and i don't know how  to deal with the executing with command line.

```
public class Jdbc {
public static DateTimeFormatter formatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-
 MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");


 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
IOException  {
    // TODO code application logic here


    Connection myConn=null;
    Statement myStmt=null;
    ResultSet myResult=null;

    String url="jdbc:MySql://localhost:3306/demo?
  autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    String user="student";
    String pass="student";

    try
    {
        myConn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        CallableStatement myCall=myConn.prepareCall("{call 
    `insert_into_mysql`(?,?,?,?,?)}");


  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("access.log");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;


    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {


    String[] i=strLine.split("[|]");
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        String timestamp = i[0];
       LocalDateTime t1=LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp,formatter);
       Timestamp ts=Timestamp.valueOf(t1);

      myCall.setTimestamp(1, ts);
      myCall.setString(2, i[1]);
      myCall.setString(3,i[2]);
      myCall.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(i[3]));
      myCall.setString(5, i[4]);


    }
    ince++;

 myCall.execute();



    }

    }

    catch(SQLException | FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }




}
}
```

Comment: If your code is working and you just want to improve it, you might consider posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Code ain't working properly because i didn't use the parsers.how to write parsers?

Comment: Can you share sample access.log file? And your for loop variable `j` hasn't been used, so what are you doing in for loop?

Comment: 2017-01-01 00:54:29.033|192.168.146.67|"GET / HTTP/1.1"|200|"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"     this a record in a log file.and i used the regex to split this logfile using delimiter(|)  and then i stored in array i and with the setstring i stored the values into db

Comment: @Akshaykumar And what about the for loop? Basically you are doing nothing in the for loop ..

Comment: ok Thank you parth.but help to me solve this.when you run your parser against this file with the following parameters

java -cp "parser.jar" com.ef.Parser --startDate=2017-01-01.00:00:00 --duration=daily --threshold=500. how to execute using command line?